# Show Woocommerce Variation dropdown in full width into box

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to make small CSS fix [into my store](https://www.thomasmckee.com/product/facebook-business-fan-page-likes/), but dont can find the right class to do that myself. i checked and found that variation dropdown is using this CSS:

```
select#pa_facebook-business-fan-page
```

but still dont know how to make that dropdown to extend to max width into that area.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm looking at the page you are referencing, you have a table cell that contains the label to the left of the select field cell. That is taking up some of the space that you want to get rid of. You can just simply hide it if you don't need.

Just need to modify the css to remove it and the select field will take up the entire width:

```
td.label {display:none;}
```

If you have other label cells on your website that you DON'T want to hide, you might need to be more specific in the CSS to target only this instance.